# Serializer nested associations include only certain attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization

My serializer looks like this:

```
class RegistrationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :status
 has_one :student
 has_one :professor
 has_one :course
end
```

Instead of returning all of the student data, I would like to do something like this:

```
class RegistrationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :status
 has_one :student [//only include :first_name]
 has_one :professor
 has_one :course
end
```

I dont want to edit student serializer directly because in other cases I will need all of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by also specifying a serializer for student. Here is an example:

```
class RegistrationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :status
 has_one :student, serializer: StudentSerializerFirstNameOnly
 has_one :professor
 has_one :course
end

class StudentSerializerFirstNameOnly < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :first_name
end
```

An alternative would be to flatten the data and have the student first name as a top level attribute:

```
class RegistrationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :status, :student_first_name
 has_one :professor
 has_one :course

 def student_first_name
   object.student.first_name
 end
end
```